# Storing data at the client side in the asp.net c#

Tags: client

I am making one application. It is a web form based application in asp.net c#. I want to include one feature in which the user can save details which he has filled and then submit it later. It really confusing for me to apply any function.

Comment: try to state what you tried to do, not just what you want to happen.

Comment: I am making an application in which I want if the user enters some value in the textbox. Then after if he logout from the panel. The value of those filled should be saved in the application.

Comment: I want that textbox value should be in the textbox if he logout from the panel.